# SQL Management Studio 18.12.1 not showing server tables

Tags: ssms

I'm having a strange issue with MSSQL Management Studio 18.12.1 (I just updated it to the last version to try to fix it). It is not showing the tables of a database.

When I click to expand the tables it starts the process:

[image]

But after a little bit it gives up and does not show anything:

[image]

The tables are not new as the server is more than an year old and I can access the data with normal queries:

[image]

Does anybody know what am I missing? Is there a timeout setting to adjust?
I tried both with SA and normal users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try login as an admin and see if you can see the tables. Your current account may be lacking the necessary permissions to view the tables.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I tried as SA as well

Comment: How many tables are on the server, out of interest? Where is the server hosted? Locally? On the Network? Another (trusted) domain) The cloud? What DBMS (SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, SQL Edge, etc) is it connected to and what version?

Comment: It's a local SQL SERVER (14.0.100) and there are 2 tables on this database. 6 in the whole server.